# Add confirm when drag and drop the kanban view in odoo 10

Tags: python, xml, odoo-10

I work with project.task model. I need to add confirmation for every stage change when user did the drag and drop. Is there any possible way.. I add validation error in write method. But Its not complete my wish. please help me

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution... 
In this case you have to change the kanban_view.js file in web_kanban module. You can replace

```
 add_record_to_column: function (event)
```

this function by this code in "kanban_view.js" file.

```
add_record_to_column: function (event) {
    var self = this;
    var column = event.target;
    var record = event.data.record;
    var data = {};
    data[this.group_by_field] = event.target.id;
    // display confirm message
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change this stage?")){
       //if click yes do this
        this.dataset.write(record.id, data, {}).done(function () {
            if (!self.isDestroyed()) {
                self.reload_record(record);
                self.resequence_column(column); 
                alert("You have change the stage!");
            }
        }).fail(this.do_reload);
    }else{// if no reload the page and remain the tile in same satage
        location.reload();
    }},
```

Comment: where is that function in odoo 12/13 version now?

Answer (score 1):

On odoo 14, here this code:

Do search "_onAddRecordToColumn" in addons/web/static/src/js/views/kanban/kanban_controller.js

then override function (with inherited module) to this:

```
_onAddRecordToColumn: function (ev) {
    var self = this;
    var record = ev.data.record;
    var column = ev.target;
    if (confirm("Are you sure want to change this stage?")){
        this.alive(this.model.moveRecord(record.db_id, column.db_id, this.handle))
            .then(function (column_db_ids) {
                return self._resequenceRecords(column.db_id, ev.data.ids)
                    .then(function () {
                        _.each(column_db_ids, function (db_id) {
                            var data = self.model.get(db_id);
                            self.renderer.updateColumn(db_id, data);
                        });
                    });
            }).guardedCatch(this.reload.bind(this));
    }else{
        this.reload();
    }
},
```